# Do I need a class variable or an instance variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I currently have an ActiveRecord model 'Team' with a column called `owner_id`.

The owner_id data is just temporary and will be redundant once after_create is called.

I want to drop the 'owner_id' column and tidy this up, but keep the functionality working. How can I do this?

For background:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :owner_id, :team_id
  has_many :team_memberships, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :team_memberships
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :team_memberships

  after_create :create_team_membership

  private

  def create_team_membership
    TeamMembership.create(
      :user_id => self.owner_id,
      :team_id => self.id,
      :roles => "site_admin")
  end
end
```

Comment: If you change owner_id as a virtual attribute I think you can drop the column. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to add an `attr_accessor` and continue assigning the `owner_id` attribute without a db column e.g. `Team.new(:owner_id => 7)`

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :owner_id
end
```

You can also avoid explicitly assigning `team_id` if you'd like:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  def create_team_membership
    team_memberships.create(:user_id => owner_id, :roles => "site_admin")
  end
end
```

Comment: I need to keep it in the attr_accessible line right?

Comment: Yep, you will need to keep it in the `attr_accessible` line. `attr_accessor` just adds an attribute to your class, and `attr_accessible` dictates which attributes can be mass-assigned.